# Sql DELETE deadlock

Tags: mysql, spring, oracle, hibernate, h2

Our application is wrote in Spring 4 + Hibernate 4 and runs on two nodes. At each night we want to run cron job (@Scheduled; let's say at 2am) that executes `DELETE` query (responsible for cleaning up db table). Table can contain a lot of entries (~60mln) and it may be possible that we will delete 30mln at once. Because of two nodes, it will be executed twice and it may be possible that we will have a deadlock on table (am I right?). How to cope with this problem (optimistic lock, pessimistic lock, some other solution)? What we want to do is to run delete operation only on one node and prevent it on the other one.

**EDIT**
Nodes are cloned but uses the same database server (oracle or mysql).

```
Server A                         Server B
(application)                    (application)
 |                                |
cron                             cron
(executed every day at 2am)      (executed every day at 2am)
 |                                |
 |                                |
  \          sql server          /
           (oracle or mysql)
```

Cron is just a spring `@scheduled` method, something like this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 2 * * *")
public void deleteEntries() {
    final String queryString = "DELETE FROM MyDto m WHERE date<:date";

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString);
    query.setParameter("date", new Date());
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

**To sum up, the problem is:**
Is it possible that queries will fail (because of execution in the same time)? If yes - how to solve the problem?

Comment: are you running mysql or oracle?

Comment: Both. It depends on client.

Comment: so are you running two node Oracle RAC or two node MySQL?  You need to give us more details on your setup

Comment: Nodes are cloned so both are running on mysql or oracle.

Comment: With info you provided I believe there won't be a deadlock, why do you think so?

Comment: So there won't be a situation where two servers will try to delete rows in the same time (cron is executed on each server at the same time) and it will fail? Is it that first query (even if has been executed 1ms earlier than the second one) will lock the table and the second one won't be executed?

Comment: But the situation, that one process is waiting for another to finish is not [deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)...

Comment: Right, wrong description, I chaged it.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use quertz-scheduler so cron will be executed only on one server at the same time.